# Has google removed the usage of UIWebView in googlesignin sdk v5.0.1?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, google-signin

Recently Apple has started giving warnings on the usage of UIWebView and asking app publisher tp update the app and use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. We are using googlesignin sdk in our app to support Google SignIn. Has google sdk remove the usage of UIWebView in their SDK?

Comment: I checked release notes (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release) but there is no confirmation on the usage of UIWebView

Comment: wasn't UIWebView removed from iOS 13 SDK?

Comment: Yes, its deprecated and during review process of app submission apple is giving warnings to remove UIWebView and use WKWebView.

Comment: so have google removed UIWebview ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it just added WKWebview but UIWebview is still used too.

verify usage of webview by running this command in your project folder via terminal

```
grep -r "UIWebView" .
```

My result is:

```
./Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth.h:    for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly *not*
./Pods/AppAuth/README.md:for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly *not*
./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser
```

**Update 21/07/2020:**

Now, just update your Podfile using latest version of GoogleSignIn

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
```

and run 'pod install' in terminal

Google already update their sdk described in changelog of AppAuth pods v.1.3.1 [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppAuth#changelog)

Comment: This might be false positive on Apple's side. Check below issue on Git
https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/449

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Because my Application getting reject because of this reason even though I am not using UIWebview. After using grep -r "UIWebView" .
I am getting same response like yours.